# DocuSign Bulk Send w/ CSV User Portal

Tags: docusignapi

The current goal is to be able to send multiple files to multiple recipients through the user portal on our website. We want to make this process as efficient as possible because we will have lots of files to sign. Lastly, I would need a way to track and save all the users.

From what I know about docusign, I am able to send a file to multiple recipients in bulk using bulk send using just the website and not having to use the API at all. Is it possible to send multiple files to multiple recipients through the same CSV? Or would it be better to just send each file separately to multiple clients and do that for each file? Also, I'm wondering if it's possible to do that in the API as well. Previously, I achieved sorting clients ID & envelope ID using the docusign api with PHP and connected it to a database. Let me know which method seems optimal for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Steven, you can use the API to use Bulk Send.
In fact, with the DocuSign eSignature API v2.1 this functionality is much improved and allows you to do all of the above.
See here for more details: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-deep-dive-discussions-bulk-send-with-esignature-api-v2-1/

Comment: Let's say, 50 different people were logged into my website. If I want different documents for different people, how would this work? Also, on the docusign website about bulk sending, it says documentation and SDK support is not currently available, so where would I go for code examples? [Currently using PHP]